# Does Xin's third hit crit count as a crit?

Tags: league-of-legends

Xin's W passive states that every third hit is a type of crit. Does this count as a real crit?

Example: Would Essence Reaver or Infinity Edge work with those crits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, any skill that states it performs a critical hit does in fact count as a real crit, and will be affected by Infinity Edge and Essence Reaver. The only difference is that most of these abilities change the crit damage modifier. In Xin's case, it changes from 200% down to 125-175% depending on skill level.

Comment: Gragas full charged Q is considered a crit. But they are not increased by IE for that matter.

Comment: @KimMinseo Really? I can't find any source that says that.

Comment: Even Anivia's E with extra dmg on is considered as crit.

Comment: You can find out easily by just going into a custom match with gragas or anivia. At the stats screen just go check the "Maximum Critical Damage" portion.